# Is there a way to detect modules in package.json that require compilation?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service

Deploying to azure sites fails if one of your npm modules requires compilation.  Is there an easy way to audit packages.json so that people not on windows could more easily know when they're going to run into issues?

Comment: can you share a module that fails to deploy because of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to terminal to your Azure website and try to install the specific npm packages there (`npm install whatever`), this way you see whether it's possible in that environment or not.

See the following on instructions to terminal to your Azure website:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about.aspx.